# Does being trained in a magic tradition count as having a spell list?

Tags: magic-items, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

As title; in other words, can my Champion (or Monk with Ki spells, or Ranger, or...) use a Wand of Heal? They are trained in Divine Spells; does that count as enough for fulfilling the "your spell list" requirement from wands? (This would also apply to scrolls). From the rules for [Casting Spells from a Wand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=757):

> To cast a spell from a wand, **it must be on your spell list**. Because you’re the one casting the spell, use your spell attack roll and spell DC. The spell is of your tradition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only classes with the Spellcasting class feature give you a spell list.  Focus spells are not on any spell list and being trained in their attack rolls and DCs does not give you a spell list.  See CRB pg. 302, [Non-Spellcasters With Focus Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=278):

> If you get focus spells from a class or other source that doesn’t
> grant spellcasting ability (for example, if you’re a monk with the Ki
> Strike feat), the ability that gives you focus spells also provides
> your proficiency rank for spell attack rolls and spell DCs, as well as
> the magical tradition of your focus spells. You gain the ability to
> Cast a Spell and use any spellcasting actions necessary to cast your
> focus spells (see below). However, you don’t qualify for feats and
> other rules that require you to be a spellcaster.

And leaving all of that aside, this clearly falls afoul of the "too good to be true" rule.

Comment: I think it's the "other rules" line that really sells it for me. Excellent find!